# Nesting visual elements with limited depth

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of viewmodels which I would like to display inside of ItemControl

The ItemsControl's ItemPanel is set to `<Canvas>` and the elements are ViewModels of different types which all inherit from one ViewModel (ElementViewModel) with `Left`, `Top`, `Width`, `Height` and `Elements` properties.
The position of elements is set by styles:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

The items are of different types and the views are retrieved by DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FirstTypeElementViewModel}">
    <local:firstElementType />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondTypeElementViewModel}">
    <local:secondElementType />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now the problem is that I would like to show the subelements of those elements for a limited depth.
I tried to move my ItemsControl to a custom control and then embed it inside each of my elements views but the reccurency in this case is not limited in any way which lead to showing all the elements with all subelements and poor performance.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Can ZIndex help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex(v=vs.95).aspx I do not remember whether ZIndex is implicitly set. If so you can try to hide elements that are deeper than some level.

Comment: @voroninp: Not really, I'm using ZIndex but it's not helpful in this scenario

Comment: Maybe you can add a property for the tree depth, and in your templates set visibility=collapsed for everything over the desired depth?

Comment: @ShayD I think it's better to use multibinding for Elements (Elements+TreeDepth) and return empty collection of elements for level deeper than required.

Comment: @voronino You are probably right, it is hard to know how the data looks like... Another option is to use a ListCollectionView with a filter.

Comment: @voroninp Can you give me any example?

Comment: A bit later, in the evening (23 MSK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a tree data structure and want to show it but not deeper than particular level. Right?

First, we need somehow get the depth of the element - its distance from the root. Let our element has additional property `int Depth` exactly for that.

```
public class ElementViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Depth {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<ElementViewModel> Elements {get; set;}

    ...
}
```

Be aware that when VM does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or does not inherit from `DependencyObject` implementing corresponding `DependecnyProperty` memory leak [may occur](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us).

So, what's next? [Multibinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx). Unlike simple Binding MultiBinding allows you to convert several values into one with the help of [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why do we need it? The idea is quite simple, we want to return empty collection of nested elements when desired level of depth is achieved.

```
public class ElementsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var elements = values[0] as IEnumerable<ElementViewModel>;
        var depth = (int)values[1];

        if (depth <= 9) // depthLimit can be passed through parameter (MultiBinding.ConverterParameter property) or via AmbientContext. Actually many ways exist.
        {
            return elements;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ElementViewModel[0];
        }
    }

    public object[] ConverBack(bject value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay">
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                 <localNamespace:ElementsConverter/>
            </MultiBinding.Converter>   
            <Binding Path="Elements"/>
            <Binding Path="Depth"/>
       </MultiBinding>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```